# Merge null Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I wrote a data model, into one class I need to merge 3 arrays. These arrays has a fixed size (of course) and initialized to null. I use this code :

```java
public static <T> T[] merge(T[]... arrays) {
    int size = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
        size += array.length;
    }

    T[] merged = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrays[0][0].getClass(), size);

    int start = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0,
           merged, start, array.length);
        start += array.length;
    }
    return (T[]) merged;
}
```

This line is not correct :

```java
T[] merged = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrays[0][0].getClass(), size);
```

I need to precise which class I use, but I get a null pointer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leverage the Collections library

```
public static <T> T[] merge(T[]... arrays) {    
    List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
    for(T[] array : arrays) {
        for(T t : array) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }
    return (T[])(list.toArray());    
}
```

Test program:

```
import java.util.*;
class Merger {
    // break out total length logic. Will probably be inlined, but this seems like
    // functionality that deserves its own method.
    public static <T> int totalLength(T[]... arrays) {
        int length = 0;
        for(T[] arr : arrays) length += arr.length;
        return length;
    }

    public static <T> T[] merge(T[]... arrays) {
        int length = totalLength(arrays);
        if(length == 0) return (T[])new Object[0];
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(length);
        for(T[] array : arrays) {
            for(T t : array) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }
        return (T[])(list.toArray(arrays[0])); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] first = new String[] { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
        String[] second = new String[] { "of", "the", "merger" };
        String[] third = new String[] { "and", "it", "works!" };

        String[] merged = merge(first,second,third);
        for(String s : merged) System.out.println(s);

        // validate that it works for merging all 0 arrays:
        merge();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an `ArrayList` with the proper capacity would be faster.

Comment: @SLaks Marginally faster, perhaps. I think that falls under the "97%" of inefficiencies to ignore until it shows itself to be problem, personally. But I agree that it would be faster to do it that way.

Comment: Indeed... I believe the `List` interface supports a `toArray()` method, but it will naturally be faster with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @bdares I would venture to say that the act of creating the array would be almost identical time on the LinkedList versus ArrayList. The difference would be in doing one memory allocation of an array as opposed to `n` Node objects.

Comment: I disagree here: `ArrayList` tends to be faster than `LinkedList` _even_ if the size is default. Non-local access in `LinkedList` makes it dying slow, unfortunately. So I'd say it's not those 97%—it's just using the simplest thing that works and only stepping away if you know why you're doing that.

Comment: @Alf perhaps we use different definitions for the same thing, but could you clarify what you mean by non-local access? If you mean random access, as in `list.get(4)` requiring iteration to the fourth element, that isn't a concern here because you only ever have to either iterate, or append to the end.

Comment: @glowcoder Non-local access is the access to non-consecutive addresses in the memory. The problem is, the memory is a "new hard drive" now, and as soon as you've missed a cache line, the things start being slow. `LinkedList` will cause cache misses approximately 10 times as often as `ArrayList` would. This turns out to be more than enough to compensate for the overflow handling. Same story with final `toArray()`—jumping the pointers is always slower than incrementing a counter in a cached structure. (Sorry, comments are limited—I'm happy to provide further details if necessary.)

Comment: @alf that's a quite intriguing theory. I would be very interested to see some benchmarks/research on it, if you happen to have some links. I don't doubt the concept, although I am skeptical of the magnitude/significance. (We are, after all, professional skeptics, no?)

Comment: @glowcoder yes we are... Still, it's [always a pain to create a "proper" benchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html) :) You can't have too many data, or GC will bite you; you can't have too few data, or system timer won't measure anything... Proper warm-up, yadda, yaddda... Anyway, try [this repository](https://github.com/alf239/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/org/acm/afilippov/lists/ListBenchmark.java)—I did my best trying not to lose anything.

Comment: @alf well when you're right you're right. And you, sir, are right. I I consistently get results of about 2.5x faster using the preallocation. While I certainly respect the fact that proper benchmarks are hard, I'm confident the even with generous error margins the preallocation will come out on top. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String[] strings = new String[3];
Class stringArrayClass = strings.getClass();
Class stringArrayComponentType = stringArrayClass.getComponentType();
System.out.println(stringArrayComponentType);
```

as described at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html#componenttype

Note also that you need to pass *component* rather than *array* type to `Arrays.create`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the type of the item in the array since there is no item in the array.
`null` doesn't have a type.

Instead, you can get the type of the array itself by writing `arrays[0].getClass().getComponentType()`